# Resource file for android manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using `<data>` in android manifest file.
I'v around 400+ such data, can i put these in different resource file and access that in manifest file.
If yes, then how?

```
<data android:host="abc.xyz"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> can i put these in different resource file and access that in manifest file

No, sorry. You might be able to put the host values themselves (e.g., `abc.xyz`) as string resources, and then refer to them as such (e.g., `@string/abc_xyz`, or whatever you called the resource). However, this will not simplify the manifest.

Comment: Is there any way i can put some external data, like some id with the url from which it is coming?

Comment: @SultanMirza: As I noted, you could move the URLs into string resources. That will just double your work, and I am not sure what benefit it will bring. You are also welcome to write your own Gradle task (or other sort of script) that generates this portion of the manifest from some data file.

Comment: I'm using deep linking in my app, is there any way by which i can associate any header or any id, which i will retrieve in my activity for checking from which url it's coming

Answer (score 0):

A Android project has only one manifest file.
What you can do is separate your project in different modules with gradle.
With this environment, the application build will merge all manifest files to generate the final APK.

Comment: Is there any way i can put some external data, like some id with the url from which it is coming?